# Identify LED driver IC MRVL

Tags: led, identification, driver, led-driver

I need help identifying that IC used in the LED driver.

MRVL

8183B0

324AFTG

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly a **Marvell 88EM8183B0-SAE2C000TAL00** which is a "dimmable, TRIAC AC/DC LED driver" according to [this page](https://www.rcscomponents.kiev.ua/marvell/page=13).

There doesn't seem to be a public datasheet available, but I found this Chinese article which has some more information (when searching the text in the image, I found [this site](https://m.elecfans.com/article/874004.html) which has some additional info):

[image]

(Source: [wenku.baidu.com](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/900755aab0717fd5370cdc00.html?_wkts_=1710178342680&bdQuery=88EM8183B0%20pdf))

---

My main clue for the manufacturer is the [Marvell 88PG847](https://www.datasheets.com/part-details/88pg847b-b1-nam1c000-t-marvell-semiconductor-36338514#datasheet) which also has a `MRVL` marking:

[image]

[image]

(Source: [aliexpress.ru](https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005001775529362.html?sku_id=12000017524252676))

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I agree with nanash1 answer.
Most of Marvell product datasheets are under NDA, so you'll probably not find the datasheet.

At least the designation (88EM8183) appears in that [catalogue](https://datasheet.octopart.com/88AP510-A1-BJV2C008-Marvell-datasheet-17899616.pdf) with the expected package (SOIC-8 EP) and is defined as a LED Driver. So it should be that component.

Comment: Thank you  so much